# Jump to next keyframe not working

Tags: animation, keyframes, shortcut

[image]

Basically, it wont let me jump to previous or next keyframes. Neither the buttons themselves or the shortcuts (up and down arrow) will work, and i cant find like a setting that has changed it for some reason, please help!

Comment: I started having this problem yesterday too. Was wondering if restarting today would fix it. Still bunked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in the new update! just get the new version and the problem is gone :)

Comment: what do you mean fixed in the new update? what update? or are you saying a new version of blender? so this is a bug in blender? btw no need to add "fixed" in the title. the "fix" is in the answer posts section :)